# android browser and re autofocus on input field

Tags: android, html, browser

I have created web application, that takes in card number from card reader that act like keyboard. I am using android tablet as terminal, and on load, I set autofocus on input field with html autofocus tag like this

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="card" name="card" type="text">
```

And everything work ok, until someone touches the screen, and input field looses focus.
Is there any way to reuturn focus back on input field? Maybe with some javascript?
On desktop browser, I would use .focus, but this does not seems to work on android browser...
Any ideas?
Thank you
Dorijan